# How can I add an 'x' number of the same image based on an output value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image

I'm very new to coding and wondering how I can insert the same image multiple times based on the input and output values. My current code for the basic addition is:

```
<form oninput="x.value=parseInt(a.value)+parseInt(b.value)">
  <input type="number" id="a" value="1"> +
  <input type="number" id="b" value="0"> =
  <output name="x" for="a b"></output>
</form>
```

Now, I want to be able to add a number of images corresponding to the output value that I obtain. How can I do this? Again, I'm sorry if the answer is obvious. I'm very new to this.

Comment: Do you want to display 10 images if output is 10?

Comment: Yes, exactly that.

Comment: I've added an answer for the question

Answer (score 0):

For good practice it's better to separate your HTML and Javascript by a [function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions).

You need to follow these steps in the function.

1. Get input values to variables.
2. Add them and display using `document.getElementById().value`
3. Add images using a loop (`c` times)

**Here is the working code**

```js
var update = () => {
  let a = parseInt(document.getElementById('a').value);
  let b = parseInt(document.getElementById('b').value);
  let c = isNaN(a + b) ? 0 : (a + b);
  document.getElementById('x').value = c;

  document.getElementById('images').innerHTML = '';
  for (let i = 0; i < c; i++) {
    document.getElementById('images').innerHTML += '<img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x150">';
  }
}
```

```html
<form oninput="update();">
  <input type="number" id="a" value="1"> +
  <input type="number" id="b" value="0"> =
  <output id="x" for="a b"></output>
</form>

<div id='images'></div>
```

Replace `http://via.placeholder.com/200x150` with your image path.

Hope it helps.